# APN Tester Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I have downloaded and installed the [APN Free Tester app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12) as i am trying to debug my Push Notification setup:

The Tester debug screen displays the following without errors however it does not how the message nor does the message appear on the app.

I can conclude that the token and the certificate are both correctly set otherwise it would generate an error

Any advise would really be appreciated

**Payload sent**:

```
{  
  "aps":{  
    "alert":"Hello from APNs Tester.",
    "badge":"1"
  }
}
```

> 2016-04-04 09:55:15 +0000: Connected  
>   2016-04-04 09:55:17 +0000: Token: <1dc3651f 54cdead8 65g5cc35 7287376d d796f3a2 2afabab1 ff80ddd4 e55eeab1>  
>  
>   2016-04-04 09:55:17 +0000: Written 92 bytes sending data to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195  
>   2016-04-04 09:55:17 +0000: Disconnected from server gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195

Answer (score 1):

I highly prefer for APNS testing tool is open source code compile and run the OSX application `Push Me Baby`.

Then follow the step.

1. Open the PushMeBaby application in Xcode.
2. Right-click on the Resources folder in Xcode and select Add Existing Files…. Select the `aps.developer.identity.cer` file that you have downloaded earlier
   [image]
3. In the ApplicationDelegate.m file, modify the code as shown below:

   ```
   - (id)init {
       self = [super init];
       if(self != nil) {
           self.deviceToken = @"38c866dd bb323b39 ffa73487 5e157ee5 a85e0b7c e90d56e9 fe145bcc 6c2c594b";

           self.payload = @"{"aps":{"alert":"You got a new message!","badge":5,"sound":"beep.wav"},"acme1":"bar","acme2":42}";

           self.certificate = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                               pathForResource:@"aps_developer_identity" ofType:@"cer"];
       }
       return self;
   ```

   }
4. Press Command-R to test the application. You will be asked to grant access to the certificate. Click Always Allow
5. If the message is pushed correctly, you should see the notification

[Download the code from here](https://github.com/stefanhafeneger/PushMeBaby)

May this helps lot.

Answer (score 0):

APN Tester Free doesn't show the sending result, it only tries to send data without confirmation.
Make sure you certification and token are both for development or production.